# The meaning of revenue

Tags: word-meaning

> There is more money potential in narcotics that in any other 
>   business. If we don't get into it, somebody else will, maybe the
>   Tattaglia family. With the **revenue** they earn they can amass more and
>   more police and political power.

I've found [**this**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/revenue) number of meanings but I can't understand which one is suitable here.

Comment: Reopening. I don't understand how this can be regarded as "entirely answerable with a dictionary" when the O.P. included a link to the dictionary! A dictionary was consulted, and now the O.P. wants to know which definition applies.

Comment: I agree that asking which definition applies is on-topic and the question should be re-opened. However, it would help if the poster explained a little more about why  choosing among the definitions is difficult. It could be that there is some wording in the definitions that we could clarify that would make this question a little less narrow.

Comment: The phrase "the revenue they earn" should have allowed the OP to figure out that the meaning here was "income" and not the department that collects taxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context it means,

> Income, especially when of an organization and of a substantial nature.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that revenue, in this context, means gross income - that is, income before expenses. Not net income, or profit.